# How can I run a piece of Mathematica code without subscribing to Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, read-eval-print-loop

Are there public or third-party REPLs or other tools I can use to run a piece of Mathematica code? I've been sent some code to evaluate, but apart from reading it as intelligently as I can, I'd also like to see its output. How do I do that?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mockmma/ or, probably more likely to accomplish what you are trying to do, politely ask Wolfram Inc for a free 30 day trial of Mathematica

Comment: You might ask the originator to export as CDF, then you can use the free player.

Comment: @agentp: Ah, I wish I'd thought of that. But I had a chance to talk to the person today and they walked me through it, which was helpful.

Comment: @Bill: MockMMA didn't cover a number of the functions used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no *practically useful* independent implementations of the Wolfram Language.

In fact there are several attempts, the most complete being http://www.mathics.org/, but none of them will be useful for actual work, and none of them will be able to run the vast majority of (even simple) Mathematica code you might come across in the wild.  These implementations are great for exploring the concepts of the core language, but they are slow and lack the myriads of builtin functions that make Mathematica useful for practical tasks such as data analysis, heavy symbolic computations, etc.

Regarding the answer by @user3061923, *Wolfram|Alpha is not Mathematica*, and cannot run Mathematica code.  It can understand a few short snippets, but it does not always interpret them in the same way as Mathematica would, and it presents the result in a completely different way than Mathematica.  It won't even be possible to reuse the last output for the next operation.

**What you *can* do,** is get a *free* Wolfram Cloud account:

- https://www.wolframcloud.com/

With even the free version of the "Wolfram Development Platform" you will be able to run most Mathematica programs unless they take too long to finish and time out.

**If you have a [Raspberry Pi computer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/),** [an (almost) complete version of Mathematica is available for it for free](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/) and will be able to run the code you have. The few limitations this version of Mathematica has are due to the performance of the Raspberry Pi, and not an effort to limit the usefulness of this free version.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity and size you could try pasting it all into Wolfram Alpha. I haven't tried this with things more complex than creating a graph for eg. http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: Thanks; this effort failed before I wrote to SO.

Comment: WolframAlpha rarely properly interprets native mathematica code, even simple one-liners.

Comment: After I've failed at using the pidgin english notation to get WolframAlpha to understand a request I have had moderate success giving it carefully selected one-liners of Mathematica code for the same request.